# android, go back to the saved data after selection in the listview

Tags: android, sql, listview

In android studio, I have an activity called ADD that let the user enter his name and birthday. when the user click on ok button the data will be saved to SQLDatabase, and then the data will be displayed in another activity in a listview. what i want is: when the user is in listview activity and click on any item of this listview , i want to take him back to the ADD activity with the saved data not with the default data.
anyone here have a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use startActivityForResult 
and onActivityResult 
Example By Two Classes A&B

Start Activity B from A

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

In Activity B when you want to get back with data

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

if You want to return without data

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
finish();
```

In Activity A :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In activity B where you provide the result intent

Answer (score 0):

You can start ADD activity using `startActivity()` with Intent containing the required data and check for that intent data in `onCreate()` of ADD activity.
If intent data is null then it means user started that activity without clicking on list item and if you get intent data , then you can extract the values you put and populate the fields with those values.

Example = 1st case :

`startActivity(new Intent(this, AddActivity.class));`

2nd case(when you click on list item) :

`startActivity(new Intent(this, AddActivity.class).putExtra("name", "your_name").putExtra("d_o_b", <your_date_of_birth>));`

And then get these data in `onCreate()` using `getIntent()`

Check `getIntent()`. If it's null then it's the usual flow else you grab values from it using -

`getIntent().getStringExtra("name")`

and follow the same procedure for dob and popluate your views using these values